# How to store big binary tree

Tags: php, binary-tree

How to store big binary trees (about thousands in depth).
We tried to store in database, in table with rows: elem, parent, left_child, right_child
but it's very slow to handle this tree (to calculate, draw a part of it).

Which way you recommend? (calculating may be done in php). May be to store it in XML or json (text file) or in some matrices?

Comment: Standard SQL setups are notoriously bad for structures like this. Representation is dead simple, but retrieval is a serious pain. Oracle and Postgres(?) have support for recursive queries via the 'connect by prior' extension, though.

Comment: What kind of database was used? Do you try Redis, MongoDB?

Comment: How many nodes does a typical tree have? A binary tree 1000 levels deep can potentially contain 2^1000 nodes - a very large number (even for a DBMS).

Comment: 2 OZ_, no, we use relational db (postgres).

Comment: 2 NealB, yes, tree may have 1000 levels...

Comment: Yes, 2^1000 = 1.07150861 × 10^301, are you sure it is a tree and not a linked list? What is the tree used for? Maybe it is better to balance the tree or use B*-trees like they are used in database design?

Comment: If you're using Postgres, try recursive WITH queries: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array or other linear store (e.g. relation id->node value) in the way that each node x has the children 2*x and 2*x+1. The problem might be that there are unused ids if the tree is unbalanced.

Sample:

```
    2---4---8
   /   \   \9
1--     5---10
   \       \11
    3---6---12
       \   \13
        7---14
           \15
```

Comment: if you want to show a subtree just compute the ids required and look up the values in batch

Answer (score 0):

Seems like writing to something like XML as you suggest would be best. Converting to XML and then back when you want to reload it would be pretty straight forward.

Comment: everything can be stored in XML, but there are soooo many options: nested elements or attributes referring to ids, or even a CDATA section containg some binary format... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use a structure like following

```
id  parent  tree    slug    name    path    children
1   0       1       root    Root    ||          |5|
2   7       1       child-1 Child 1 |1-5-8-7|   |3|
```

It is super easy to query huge depth trees, because the query is linear.
There is a bit more data in each line, but that makes it quicker.

For example you can get a whole subtree with a simple query like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `'.$this->_table_name.'` WHERE 
            `path` LIKE "%-:parent-%"
            OR `path` LIKE "%|:parent-%"
            OR `path` LIKE "%-:parent|%"
            OR `path` LIKE "%|:parent|%"';

$result = $this->_db->custom_query($sql, array('parent' => $root->id));
```

And then build the depth array by a simple function:

```
private function _build_tree(Node $root, $data)
    {
        $mapped_node = array(
            'node' => $root,
            'subnodes' => array()
        );

        if ( !empty($root->children) )
        {
            foreach( $root->children as $child )
            {
                if ( array_key_exists($child, $data) )
                {
                    $mapped_node['subnodes'][] = $this->_build_tree($data[$child], $data);
                }
            }
        }

        return $mapped_node;
    }
```

NOTE! When I get back the children and path columns, I split them into arrays for PHP to be able to better work with them.